# wordpress next post in same child category

Tags: wordpress, categories

I have a category structure that is something like:

```
-parent category
    -sub category 1
    -sub category 2
```

I'm using the the following to display the next and previous posts in the same category

```
<?php previous_post_link('&laquo; %link', 'Previous post in category: %title', TRUE); ?>
<?php next_post_link('%link &raquo;', 'Next post in category: %title', TRUE); ?>
```

problem is its taking me through the parent category - can I get it to go to the next post in the same sub category?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can. Here is the link that explain in detail how you can achieve this thing. I hope this link will help. http://yondershore.com/paging-through-sub-category-posts/

Comment: This is what I came up with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946468/advanced-wordpress-single-post-pagination-exclude-category-browse-through-on/13946469

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the function reference
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link
you see it has 3 parameters. The 3rd is a list of categories to ignore, so I guess you can just add the parent category there.

Comment: Thanks - I have checked the codex. Seems a bit long winded - it means I need to do either conditionals or seperate templates for each category in which I want to place the menu - in this instance a conditional statement or seperate template for sub-cat 1 and sub-cat 2. Not so bad with only 2 cats - but with 20 it might become very fiddly.

Comment: can't you just make a list of all categories whit childs, and always ignore all categories in that list

Comment: somthing like: $parents = array(); foreach($categories as $curent_cat) { if($curent_cat['parent']) { $parents[$curent_cat['parent']] = $curent_cat['parent']; } } $ignored_categories = implode(" AND ", $parents);

Comment: that seems more along the right lines - but I wouldn't know where to start to implement that!! Thanks